# PHP - LoadIn File to Import TXT/CSV to SQL does not work on Server, But works locally?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Am wondering if someone can validate my code, 
I seem to have a bit of a issue when running this code on a Linux server.

If I run this local host (Xammp) This runs through without any errors, no timing out.

Script created database and populated from TXT or CSV.

When I move the scrip to the web server to run 
I end up with the following error:

```
Error creating table: Table 'Sales' already exists
Error: LOAD DATA INFILE 'Salest.CSV' REPLACE INTO TABLE `Sales` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES
Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I get a access denied? but if I delete the table: 
and re-run the code:

```
Table Sales created successfully
Error: LOAD DATA INFILE 'Salest.CSV' REPLACE INTO TABLE `Sales` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES
Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Of course the username and password are correct, as it has created the table within the database, Why am I experiencing an issue when populating it?

What am I missing?

```
<?php

ini_set("memory_limit",-1);    // Unlimited Memory  handle this properly just quick internal testing


        // Lets start by connecting to the Database
$databasehost = "localhost";    // Connection Local? Remote?
$databasename = "DBNAME";       // Database Name
$databasetable = "DBTABLE"; // Database Table
$databaseusername ="USERNAME";    // Database Username
$databasepassword = "";       // Database Password
$filename = "Sales.txt";    // File we will import (This will be picked up from FTP
$fieldseparator = "\t";             // Field Deliminator / separator
$lineseparator = "\n";              // New Line Deliminator / separator

/********************************/
$addauto = 0;                             // add an empty field at the beginning of these records 1 = yes / 0 = no
/********************************/

/********************************/
$save = 0;                                // Convert the file to a SQL file   0 = Import to MYSQL or 1 = Save to SQL File
$outputfile = "output.sql";     // The name of the SQL file you are going to save
/********************************/


// As the above is configurable, we should use a config file for the above, and use the code beloew in static file
// below code can be one one file, and we can use a FTP Collect routine and call this after.


if (!file_exists($filename)) {                                               // Does the file exist?
        echo "File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.\n";  // Print message if it does not
        exit;                                                                // Exit out of it
}

$file = fopen($filename,"r");               // open the CSV or TXT file  (Test if this works on TXT may need re-formatting)

if (!$file) {                               // statement if problem opening file
        echo "Error opening data file.\n";  // Print the error message
        exit;                               // exit out
}                                           // end of statement

$size = filesize($filename);                    //check file exists but has a valid size (not 0kb)

if (!$size) {                               // If the size is 0kb i.e. not valid then error
        echo "File is empty.\n";            // rpint the error message
        exit;                               // exit out
}                                           // end of statement

$filecontent = fread($file,$size);          //Declare varable CSV file - Read in the file and size

fclose($file);                              // close the file


                                // Now lets connect to the database and select the database we will work from
$conn = new mysqli($databasehost, $databaseusername, $databasepassword, $databasename);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


                            // Now we are connected to the Database, Lets create the table we will start to import data too.
              // List of colums we will be using in the Sales Table:
              //uniquekey, type, itemno, styleno, styledesc, variatdesc, date, hour, day, month, year, locn, dept2, dept1, dept0, depta, season, reason, supplier, brand, fullprice, soldat, cost, margin, qty, cashier, custkey, stockkey
$sqlcreate = "CREATE TABLE $databasetable (

uniquekey Int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
type VARCHAR(20) NULL,
itemno Int(11) NULL,
styleno Int(11) NULL,
styledesc VARCHAR(40) NULL,
variatdesc VARCHAR(20) NULL,
date DATE,
hour Int(11) NULL,
day Int(11) NULL,
month Int(11) NULL,
year Int(11) NULL,
locn VARCHAR(20) NULL,
dept2 VARCHAR(20) NULL,
dept1 VARCHAR(20) NULL,
dept0 VARCHAR(20) NULL,
depta VARCHAR(20) NULL,
season VARCHAR(20) NULL,
reason VARCHAR(20) NULL,
supplier VARCHAR(20) NULL,
brand VARCHAR(20) NULL,
fullprice FLOAT(9,3) NULL,
soldat FLOAT(9,3) NULL,
cost FLOAT(9,3) NULL,
margin FLOAT(9,3) NULL,
qty Int(11) NULL,
cashier VARCHAR(40) NULL,
custkey Int(11) NULL,
stockkey VARCHAR(40) NULL

)";

if ($conn->query($sqlcreate) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table <b>" . $databasetable ."</b> created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}



// exit ;   // Exit was used to end the script early, Write the code, and test the code in 2 sections.

// Now the table is created, How about grabbing a text file for an example and seeing if we can put it into the SQL
// So Another SQL Query  Instead of using INTO Table ****(Tablename)****  We will use REPLACE INTO TABLE
// So if the same data is re-sent up, it will replace its original, Need to check this method does not have issues
// down the line with Indexs, If so, then the replace statement could be met with When log_time is > than original

$sqlimport = "
    LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename'
    REPLACE INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$fieldseparator'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    " ;

if ($conn->query($sqlimport) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br>Data Imported from " .$filename." OK!";
} else {
    echo "<br>Error: " . $sqlimport . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the size of the file?

Comment: 300+ MB  

Its format if helps: 
1,S,706,50,Doc Ankle Boots,Black 4/37,130601,10,SHOP,BOOT,STRT,,,SS-12,,Core,,24.99,24.99,10.00,10.83,1,,10001,0000706SHOP

2,S,1726,123,Bridal/Prom Shoes,Gold 3/36,130601,12,SHOP,SHOE,CLOSE,,,SS-12,,Fusion,,29.99,29.99,10.00,14.99,1,,10005,0001726SHOP

x2 lines

Comment: Most likely permissions.  Try something like "show grants for USERNAME@%" in MySQL on the Linux box.

Although it does seem weird to be able to drop and create a table and not populate it, but that's exactly what I might expect if the grant wasn't what it needs to be ... hmm.

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `USERNAME`.* TO 'USERN...    (Replaced username for obvious reasons)

Comment: Have you checked you php.ini file for upload_max_filesize?  You might need to increase this.

Comment: Upload max file - The file is already present on the server, so would it be this flag or, Post_Max_Size

Comment: did you change the upload_max_filesize and then it worked?  Also there is a possibility that you are receiving that error while it is still processing because it is soo big.

Comment: post_max_size 1G 
memory_limit 1G
max_input_time 19200
max_execution_time 19200
upload_max_filesize 1G
Are the settings i think that could effect it, And i believe 1 GB is more than enough.
(These are the settings that are already on the server)

Answer (score 1):

So after alot of trial and error, i was able to resolve the issue.

```
$sqlimport = "
LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename'
```

replaced with:

```
$sqlimport = "
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename'
```

Give me a new error Along the lines of Local command not allow with MySQL Version. 
SQL Statement: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile' 
Give me the result of:  local_infile    OFF

Bingo!!! Changed to On, and rebooted and script works as expected.

Thanks for  your help and suggestions.